# Telegram Bot not responding after 3rd function call

Tags: python, html, bots, telegram

The issue is that the third function never seems to respond.
I haven't been able to find a reason why this happens in the telegram documentation.
Please let me know if you have this issue or seen it and know the solution.
Even a post that references an issue like this would work.
Thank you so much for the assistance.

```
from email import message
import os
import re
import html
import json
import telebot
import requests
import http.client
from pytube import *
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# Creating hiding, and using API Keys
API_KEY = os.getenv("API_KEY")
RAPID_KEY = os.getenv("RAPID_API")
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)

@bot.message_handler(commands="start")

# Creating a help message for guidance on how to use bot.
def help(message):

    # Trying to send help message, if unable to send, throw an error message for the user.
    try:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Use \"Youtube\" and the video name to search for a video.\n")
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "There was an error fetching help, the bot may be offline.\n")
 
# Checking data and seeing if the word "YouTube" was used in order to start the search
def data_validation(message):
    query = message.text.split() 
    if("youtube" not in query[0].lower()):  # Set flag false if regular text
        return False
    else:
        return True

@bot.message_handler(func=data_validation)

# Searching for youtube videos
# using RAPID API
def search(message):
    query = message.text.split()
    
    # Check if data is valid, and change variable to be lowercase for easy use.
    if(data_validation(message) == True and query[0].lower() == "youtube"):
        try:
            if(data_validation(message) == True and query[1].lower() != "-d"):
    
                # Removing the word "YouTube" and sending the results to the YouTube search engine.
                for item in query[:]:
                    if(item.lower() == "youtube"):
                        query.remove(item)
                        search_query = ' '.join(query)
                    else:
                        pass #If it's not term we're looking to convert, ignore it.

                # RAPID API for Youtube
                try:

                    url = "https://youtube-search-results.p.rapidapi.com/youtube-search/"
                    querystring = {"q":search_query}

                    headers = {
                        "X-RapidAPI-Key": RAPID_KEY,
                        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "youtube-search-results.p.rapidapi.com"
                    }

                    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring) # Grabbing response information from URL
                    request = json.loads(response.text) # Parsing json string for python use
                    
                    # Testing to see if the RAPID API service responds and is online.
                    if(response.status_code == 503):

                        # If the service is not online, let the user know.
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"The RAPID API service appears to be offline try back later.\n") 

                    if(response.status_code == 429):

                        # If the service has reached max quota for the day, let the user know.
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Max quota reached, try back in 24 hours.\n")

                    # Grabbing first link from json text and sending direct url and title.
                    first_link = str((request["items"][0]["url"]))

                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{first_link}\n") # Sending first link that was queried.

                # If there are no results found for the requested video, sending an error message to alert the user.
                except:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Unable to load video.\n")
        except:
                pass #ignoring if not the phrase we're looking for.

def test(message):
    string = message.text.split()
    print(string)

    if(string[0] == "test" and data_validation(message) == True):
        print("This is a test and i should be printed")   
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Test message")

# Stay alive function for bot pinging / communication
bot.infinity_polling(1440)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using "if **name** == '**main**':" and keeping all the functions in "main():" as a function handler everything ran smoothly.
I'm still trying to figure out why this works.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem in your code is your first line

`from email import message`

You import the message from email and also pass a parameter to the data_validation function with the same name, then return False in the data_validation function. If you return false, the function never will be executed.

first give an alias to first line you imported

**Try This**

```
from email import message as msg
import os
import re
import html
import json
import telebot
import requests
import http.client
from pytube import *
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# Creating hiding, and using API Keys
API_KEY = os.getenv("API_KEY")
RAPID_KEY = os.getenv("RAPID_API")
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)


# Creating a help message for guidance on how to use bot.
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def help(message):

    # Trying to send help message, if unable to send, throw an error message for the user.
    try:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Use \"Youtube\" and the video name to search for a video.\n")
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "There was an error fetching help, the bot may be offline.\n")

# Checking data and seeing if the word "YouTube" was used in order to start the search
def data_validation(message):
    query = message.text.split() 
    print(query)
    if("youtube" not in query[0].lower()):  # Set flag false if regular text
        return False # if you return false, the function never will be executed
    else:
        return True


# Searching for youtube videos
# using RAPID API
@bot.message_handler(func=data_validation)
def search(message):
    query = message.text.split()
    print(query) # if function executed you see the query result
    # Check if data is valid, and change variable to be lowercase for easy use.
    if(data_validation(message) == True and query[0].lower() == "youtube"):
        try:
            if(data_validation(message) == True and query[1].lower() != "-d"):

                # Removing the word "YouTube" and sending the results to the YouTube search engine.
                for item in query[:]:
                    if(item.lower() == "youtube"):
                        query.remove(item)
                        search_query = ' '.join(query)
                    else:
                        pass #If it's not term we're looking to convert, ignore it.

                # RAPID API for Youtube
                try:

                    url = "https://youtube-search-results.p.rapidapi.com/youtube-search/"
                    querystring = {"q":search_query}

                    headers = {
                        "X-RapidAPI-Key": RAPID_KEY,
                        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "youtube-search-results.p.rapidapi.com"
                    }

                    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring) # Grabbing response information from URL
                    request = json.loads(response.text) # Parsing json string for python use

                    # Testing to see if the RAPID API service responds and is online.
                    if(response.status_code == 503):

                        # If the service is not online, let the user know.
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"The RAPID API service appears to be offline try back later.\n") 

                    if(response.status_code == 429):

                        # If the service has reached max quota for the day, let the user know.
                        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Max quota reached, try back in 24 hours.\n")

                    # Grabbing first link from json text and sending direct url and title.
                    first_link = str((request["items"][0]["url"]))

                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{first_link}\n") # Sending first link that was queried.

                # If there are no results found for the requested video, sending an error message to alert the user.
                except:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Unable to load video.\n")
        except:
                pass #ignoring if not the phrase we're looking for.

def test(message):
    string = message.text.split()
    print(string)

    if(string[0] == "test" and data_validation(message) == True):
        print("This is a test and i should be printed")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Test message")

# Stay alive function for bot pinging / communication
bot.infinity_polling(1440)
```

Comment: well spotted.  i would also suggest that the wildcard is removed `from pytube import *` and changed to an alias like this `import pytube as ptb`..

Comment: I didn't notice that add-on, I'll have to remove it all together because i don't believe I'm using it at all. I may have been testing something with it but I'm currently not using that library.